# Align Data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read multiple csv files and store the content of these files in a panda dataframe as shown below:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O24ii.jpg.)
As shown in image ecg is a pd.Dataframe variable and it contains the data of two .csv file but they are not align. Both contains NaN along the rows.

Please describe a method to align the data and remove NaN.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example of your problem? It's difficult to figure out what's going on from your jupyter-notebook screenshot.

Comment: Suppose I have two .csv files contains the data along rows and use only one column and both data have different lengths. I am trying to read these files one by one and storing the content of both files in pd.Dataframe(df = pd.Dataframe()).
df contains the data of both files along 2 columns which looks like this:
df
1          NaN
10        NaN
23        NaN
234      NaN
----       -----
NaN     45
NaN     92

now problem is data of both files when stored in df is not properly aligned and it contains some NaN elements. so i want to remove there and make the data in df well aligned.

Answer (score 0):

As it is unclear from your question, please check this example for reference, it might help u otherwise leave a comment will try to resolve issue here:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                   [3, 4, 6, 1],
                   [np.nan, 8, np.nan, 5],
                   [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 44]],
                  columns=list('ABCD'))

df.fillna(0)
```

Hope it helps.